# Change color of image

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

IS it possible to change color of image from code ?

Comment: change image's color like when open image in MAC and change color from  Tools->Adjust Color

Comment: I think you might need to be a little bit more specific about what you mean. Do you want to access individual color pixels or draw a new image programattically? Be very specific.

Comment: I just want to change image's color like when we change image's color from MAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](http://www.developers-life.com/change-color.html) from Change RGB color of the picture - Notes of a Developer

Answer (score 0):

What do u mean by change color of image? u can change the UIImageView's image in code by using `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];` where the *myImage.png* is in ur project's Resource folder. Or u can use `[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` to set ur UIImageView to red color.

Comment: I know that.i want to change image's color and save the image

Comment: oh sry i don't know how to do that neither.